# SignalR with Firefox shows XML Parsing Error in console

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr

I am using signalr 2.2.2 in an MVC application. Everything works ok apart from the fact, that every time the application navigates to another page a console error in the following form is shown:

```
XML Parsing Error: no root element found
Location: http://localhost/signalr/abort?transport=serverSentEvents&clientProtocol=1.5&connectionToken=2elX1XZHXH0xmQaLZKyHUFW5Z2rb2DGRYEI...
```

This only happens in firefox. Does anybody know how to fix this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It might be related to known [Firefox-884693](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=884693) issue. Based on some research ([here](https://github.com/DevExpress/AjaxControlToolkit/commit/70ea1d9f632bf176800153cb09859247c1bcc7ed) and [here](https://chiragrdarji.wordpress.com/2010/02/17/xml-parsing-error-no-element-found/)), and [searching](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=%22Response.End%22&type=) through SignalR code, a fix would be to assign `Content-Type` before response is sent back. So following files might have to be changed.

```
// src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core/PersistentConnection.cs
private static Task FailResponse(IResponse response, string message, int statusCode = 400)
{
    response.StatusCode = statusCode;
    // response.ContentType = "text/plain";  // <--- ADD THIS LINE
    return response.End(message);
}


// src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core/Transports/WebSocketTransport.cs
private Task AcceptWebSocketRequest(Func<IWebSocket, Task> callback)
{
    var accept = _context.Environment.Get<Action<IDictionary<string, object>, WebSocketFunc>>(OwinConstants.WebSocketAccept);

    if (accept == null)
    {
        // Bad Request
        _context.Response.StatusCode = 400;
        // _context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";  // <--- ADD THIS LINE
        return _context.Response.End(Resources.Error_NotWebSocketRequest);
    }

    Action<IWebSocket> prepareWebSocket = socket => {
        _socket = socket;
        socket.OnClose = _closed;
        socket.OnMessage = _message;
        socket.OnError = _error;
    };

    var handler = new OwinWebSocketHandler(callback, prepareWebSocket, _maxIncomingMessageSize);
    accept(null, handler.ProcessRequest);
    return TaskAsyncHelper.Empty;
}
```

This would require submitting bug to open source project, forking, applying changes, testing it, creating pull request etc. which is longer project than I have time right now. If anyone wants to test this theory, thanks.